# Cannot set background color of the selected tab programmatically in ViewPager

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I want to set BackgroundColor of the selected TAB by code in ViewPager.

For far what I have done is:-

```
tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#92278F"));
tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(50);
tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

But I cannot achieve it.

If the selected Color is RED then the TAB should reflect as RED in COLOR for the selected TAB and white as selected TEXT COLOR. 
I can do it by XML code but I am not getting any idea how to achieve it by CODE(dynamically)

Please help me.

Comment: What's `tabs` ? Is it `TabLayout`?

Comment: Yes...It is TabLayout...

Answer (score 0):

This is how it will look like-
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRPW3.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otHo5.png)

Here is the code:

Make 3 drawable files for background, selected and unselected states-

tab_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

tab_background_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#87CEFA" />
</shape>
```

tab_background_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
</shape>
```

Then finally add tablayout styles in styles.xml

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#ff00ff</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
</style>
```